# Making working copy of file geodatabase in same folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase

I am trying to create a working copy of the Lesson 5 geodatabase shown in the screen capture so I can work with the metadata. I can't recall how to do that. Should I simply right click `new>`

Then name it, then copy and past the two features?  I tried it and paste is not available in the new working file

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you don't have write access to that folder location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PolyGeo has it right.

In your Catalog window, just right-click the file geodatabase (*.gdb) and choose Copy, then right-click the folder and choose Paste.

Answer (score 3):

In your **Catalog** window, just right-click the **file geodatabase (*.gdb)** and choose **Copy**, then right-click the **folder** and choose **Paste**.

If Paste is greyed out check that you have write permission to that folder using Windows Explorer.

Comment: this how we copy and paste geodatabases - it is the quickest way.

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned above, if the paste option is greyed out you most likely don't have write permissions to that directory. That's why I would recommend working in a separate directory (of which you have write access to), or create your own.

You can create a new folder in ArcCatalog or your explorer window. Right click the geodatabase in question > Copy. In ArcCatalog navigate to the directory and right click  paste.

Alternatively you could use the [Copy Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000051000000)

Answer (score 0):

One (perhaps less elegant) solution would be to utilize the Export/Import option available in ArcCatalog.

You can use the Export to XML option in ArcCatalog, and then Import this into a new file geodatabase.  See a brief how-to description in the second table on page 2, [here](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0309/files/9reasons.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact replica (which I think is what you're looking for) you can also just copy and paste the folder from within windows explorer, bypassing ArcMap/Catalog all together.  It's a folder that is named Lesson5.gdb; just copy and paste it like any other folder on your computer.  It's full of the little jibberish files that make up the file geodatabase, but if you keep everything all together it's just fine.

One thing to keep in mind: if you copy to the same directory, windows automatic renaming scheme to avoid duplicates will name it "Lesson5.gdb - Copy", which you'll need to rename "Lesson5_Copy.gdb" so ArcGIS will read it.